# Ubuntu 20.04 Black Screen when opening new apps/ windows

Tags: upgrade, dell, screen, 20.04

Anyone encountered an issue where the screen will turn black every now and then for about 1 or 2 seconds, when a new browser is opened or when a headphone is plugged in. I tried changing refresh rate and power setting but with no luck.

Comment: What graphics card/driver are you using, and have you attempted a driver update?

Comment: im using Mesa Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics (ICL GT2). i checked and there is no update via apt or software-update. those are the only ones that i tried.

Comment: hmmm... for some reason, seems to be related to when i get a system sound alert. it black/blank the screen and when the display came back, the sound / alert follows